# Same class as a member inside a class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, struct

Sorry I ill formed the question [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70100425/same-class-as-a-member-inside-a-class-in-c). The piece of code is something like:

```
class Bar
{
    public:
        // some stuff

    private:
        struct Foo
        {
            std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Foo>> subFoo;
            // some other basic variables here
        };

        Foo foo;
};
```

I got the basic idea about `subFoo`. But I am wondering that a single instance of `Bar` will contain only a single instance of `Foo` that is `foo` member variable? So a single instance/object of Bar will not be able to map multiple `Foo` inside the `subFoo`?

It feels like I am missing something here, can anyone break it down for me?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. No, because even though there is a single `subFoo` inside `Foo` inside `Bar`, that `subFoo` is a container (`unordered_map`) which may have arbitrary number of values.

Comment: @yeputons can you give an example with two elements inside `subFoo`, it will be clear enough for me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more misunderstandings about nested class definitions than there are actual benefits. In your code it really does not matter much and we can change it to:

```
struct Foo {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Foo>> subFoo;
    // some other basic variables here
};

class Bar
{
        Foo foo;
};
```

`Foo` is now defined in a different scope and it is no longer `private` to `Bar`. Otherwise it makes no difference for the present code.

> I am wondering that a single instance of Bar will contain only a single instance of Foo that is foo member variable?

Yes.

> So a single instance/object of Bar will not be able to map multiple Foo inside the subFoo?

`subFoo` is a map holding unique pointers to `Foo`s. `Bar::foo` is not managed by a unique pointer, hence placing them in `subFoo` is not possible without running into a double free error. `std::unique_ptr` can be used with a custom deleter, but thats not the case here. Hence you cannot store a unique pointer to `Bar::foo` in any `Foo::subFoo`. You can however, store unique pointers to other `Foo`s in `Foo::subFoo`.

Comment: just a small question, `Foo` is private to `Bar`, so I am wondering can it access another `Foo` instance from another `Bar`?

Comment: @DonBaka any `Foo` can access another `Foo`s members. Also note that nested classes defined in the `private` section arent as private as you might expect. For example if `Bar` has a public method with a `Foo` parameter or return type then the type isnt really private

Comment: one last question, another `Foo` means another `Bar` as well? (that is number of `Foo` instance == number of `Bar` instance)?

Comment: @DonBaka franky, thats very basic questions and I think the best I can do is to refer you to a good C++ book https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list